# Gulp: recursively add source file in the middle of pipe?

Tags: gulp

In gulp I want to deal with some files but I do not know all of the files I want to deal with at the time I write gulp.src([...]). I can only know some files at that time and other files I want to deal with depend on the known files dependencies. My question is is there a way that can add the source file in the middle of pipe? Pseudo code:

```
gulp.src([some files I already knew]).pipe(gp_tap(function(file){
// some actions;
// get file dependencies
// Here I want to add the dependencies as the source file
}))
```